# на андроид 9 не могу получить данные от встроеного сканера. На андроид 5 всё работает

Tags: android, android-intent

Использую intent

[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA" })]

Предполагаю, что нужно какое-то разрешение, но я не знаю какое.

Comment: скорее всего вы объявляли через манифест. Начиная с 8 андроида так делать не стоит.  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.